qsave fail with large R object
I'm using Rstudio server and the library qs to read/save faster than with save/readRDS because I have very large Seurat object >20 Gb.
When I try to qsave smaller object, like character or small vectors, qsave works perfectly. However when I try to do it with Seurat object I have the error:
Error in qsave(test, "file.qs") : basic_ios::clear: iostream error

I've tried looking on internet, people seem to have similar error messages, but not for the same reason. Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Some parts of the answer to your same question cross-posted on 'solutionfall' sound reasonable. Did you look at your memory use while trying to save? Does it work when you save the same object with save() or saveRDS(), checking whether this is a qsave issue.

Yes saveRDS() works and the memory use is ok. Find out it was an authorization problem in the folder I wanted to save into
